# How much base health does Talion have?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

How much health does Talion have to start with? I keep seeing runes that restore a set amount of health (as opposed to a percentage), but it would be nice to have a baseline to know what that number actually means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since getting all the upgrades doubles your starting health, and they're all 20 and there's five of them, you start with 100 health points.